# How does Google analytics consider an organic session that pays after 3 hours?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, conversions

I am wondering how Google considers traffic in the described situation:

A user visits the site through organic search, visits a product and leaves the page opened for more than 30 mins so that the sessions will get expired.

Then proceeds the purchase and buys that product.

In Google analytics data, is that purchase considered as an **Organic traffic purchase** or **Direct traffic conversion** or what?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Analytics, outside the Attribution and Multi-Channel Funnel reports, by default the conversion is attributed to the last non-direct source/medium/channel. So in this case the sale will be attributed to organic in the non-MCF reports (e.g. Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Channels).

It is possible to check this relatively easily if you have the transaction Id and the Google Analytics add-in for Google Sheets. You'd make one report to query the Reporting API and another report to query the MCF API,  in each report filtering for the given transactionId, with the dimension as channel or source/medium.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer is wrong - in standard reports Google Analytics uses last non-direct click attribution.

"The Last Non-Direct Click model ignores direct traffic and attributes 100% of the conversion value to the last channel that the customer clicked through from before buying or converting. Analytics uses this model by default when attributing conversion value in non-Multi-Channel Funnels reports."

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1665189?hl=en

Comment: That is a nice model.  Where does it say that standard reports use it?  That page only says that some funnel reports use it.

Comment: It does not only say that some funnel reports use it, the quote actually says " Analytics uses this model by default when attributing conversion value in non-Multi-Channel Funnels reports." i.e anywhere that is not a Multi-Channel Funnels report, uses last non direct click.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation it is a Direct session. Since the "organic" one has expired, new one is started. I do not know what kind of web-shop you are running, ie. *does the product have a long description to read* or something similar which can cause users to spend more than 30 minutes without performing a hit. But you may consider adding some events or extending a session time.

Comment: I don't know how most people shop, but I often leave browser tabs for products I might buy open for hours or even days while I think about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The products need the seller confirmation before they can be bought.

Comment: No problem . 
@StephenOstermiller I am glad you said that, if that is the occasion for most people that shop, which we will know through various events and goals, that means that our page/offer/products info/position etc.. Needs attention and optimization. That is the point of our work as far as you ask me :)